# How Images can be added to HTML in Django, As i tried by static folder but still not getting image on html page

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

{% load static %}

Why this is not working in my case ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't offer any code I will provide you the basic approach:

**html**

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'images/justinbieber_avatar.png' %}">
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

with a directory `project/static/images/justinbieber_avatar.png`

Make sure to run

```
$ py manage.py collectstatic
```

if in production.

Comment: @Mrt_jay Cool! Glad to help, would be smart if you accept the answer then. Thanks!

Comment: one more thing here,  this is working fine with .svg files but when it comes with .png or .jpg .. wont work, wha is the  reason...

Comment: @Mrt_jay it works the very same way. Just make sure that the files are in the directory and you have the correct filename in your <img src="....">

Comment: {% load static %} 
<img src="{% static 'admin/img/calendar-icons.svg' %}"/>  works fine, but
    {% load static %} 
<img src="{% static 'admin/img/mypic.jpeg' %}"/>  does not work, path and name are correct...

Comment: use relative links in your href tag. In your settings.py you define the base path for static files, and then you go from there when defining href links