# django css background-image url not working

Tags: css, django

so i have this header-task class but for some reason the background-image wont show up but when i click the url in visual studio code its show me the image from the url. does anyone know what's the problem to my code here? thanks

```
 .header-task{
  background-image: url("..\image\nightlandscape.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
}
```

here is the picture of my visual studio code when I click the URL image

[image]

[image: my structure file]

Comment: What is your folder structure? I believe that the path to your image is incorrect. Have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: i edit my question so you can see my folder structure

Comment: assets is my static_root folder

Comment: Please see this post to get a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62471742/how-images-can-be-added-to-html-in-django-as-i-tried-by-static-folder-but-still/62472059#62472059

Comment: i don't think the static is the problem because i load the static in my html one and it work perfectly maybe the url on my css is the problem

Comment: i know its dumb for me to say this do i need to put the {% load static %} too in my css?

Comment: i fix this by putting the background url in my div html but i am still confused why the url work there but not in the css

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging but personally I do not have the environment to test it out. So you might need to check it for yourself.

Can you please try the below:

```
 .header-task{
  background-image: url("static(image/nightlandscape.jpg"));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
}
```

If your STATIC_URL is '/static/' (I believe that is in settings.py), this will be rendered as:

```
 .header-task{
  background-image: url("/static/image/nightlandscape.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Another possibility:

```
 .header-task{
  background-image: url('{% static 'nightlandscape.jpg' %}') or url('{% static "/img/nightlandscape.jpg" %}')
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
}
```

but for that I think you would need to load static files first: `{% load static%}` in your `HTML` and then load the stylesheet.

```
<head>
    <style>
        {% include "path/to/my_styles.css" %}
    </style>
</head>
```

Possibly simply changing `url("..\image\nightlandscape.jpg")` to `url("../image/nightlandscape.jpg")`

Comment: background-image: url("/static/image/nightlandscape.jpg"); only this one worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me:

```
background-image: url( '/static/images/moon.jpg');
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I do have a similar use case, I call the background image in the CSS file as below

```
.class-name{
  background-image: url('../img/img.png');
}
```

And I have a folder structure which corresponds as:

```
Static
   Css
      file.css
   Img
      img.png
```

It might be the folder structure that it can't resolve.